# Undeclared Identifier 'webview'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am building a tab bar application with a different pdf in each tab. I have two sets of view controllers. Each have this relative code

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Winter_Newsletter"
                                                     ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I keep receiving an error "undeclared identifier 'web view'" What am I doing Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing in the code  two versions of webView(**capital V**) and webview(**small v**)

```
[webView loadRequest:request];
[webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

And if you are using auto-synthesize then it sould be

`self.webView` or `_webView`

Answer (score 0):

And also, don't forget to make a property of the web view and control drag to hook it up!